# How to fetch data using AJAX LARAVEL with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

can you suggest a way on how can I fetch a data using AJAX LARAVEL with pagination? I already have a fetch function using AJAX and it is already working, but I wanted to add a pagination. Thank you in advance.

This is my controller

```
public function fetchAllCustomer()
{

    $customers = Customer::all();
    return response()->json([
        'customers'=>$customers,
    ]);
}
```

This is my AJAX function

```
function fetchstudent() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/fetch-customer",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
              // console.log(response);
              $('tbody').html("");
              $.each(response.customers, function (key, item) {
                  $('tbody').append('<tr>\
                      <td>' + item.first_name + '</td>\
                      <td><button type="button" value="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-primary editbtn btn-sm">Edit</button></td>\
                      <td><button type="button" value="' + item.id + '" class="btn btn-danger deletebtn btn-sm">Delete</button></td>\
                  \</tr>');
              });
          }
      });
  }
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination

The docs are good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel Docs - Pagination using Eloquent:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results

Instead of:

```
public function fetchAllCustomer()
{

$customers = Customer::all();
return response()->json([
    'customers'=>$customers,
]);
}
```

Should be:

```
    public function fetchAllCustomer()
{
    $customers = Customer::paginate(15);
    // handle your pagination links in AJAX
    $paginationLinks = (string) $customers->links();
    return response()->json([
        'customers'  =>$customers,
        'pagination' => $paginationLinks
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hello sir @calebe I tried this before but I'm having an error, data displayed is undefined an per inspect , in console, Cannot read properties of null (reading 'first_name')

Comment: Uncomment this line 'console.log(response);' and inspect what is coming from the method response..

Comment: Hi sir , It works! It gave the right response, but I think I display it wrong using the response.customer, is there way to fix it sir

Comment: I have error on this part  <td>' + item.first_name + '</td>\

Comment: Try to use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger after your each() iteration and inspect whats coming from item

Comment: it holds this first 

item: 1
key: "current_page"

when click continue it holds this   
                                                                                                                              
item: Array(2)
0: {id: 97, first_name: 's', last_name: 'test', gender: 0, birthdate: '2022-03-31', …}
1: {id: 96, first_name: 's', last_name: 'test', gender: 1, birthdate: '2022-03-24', …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
key: "data"

Comment: sorry I'm to confuse how can I access it

Comment: use javascript syntax forEach, should be: response.customer.forEach(function(data){} https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: hi sir , I tried it and having an error ,"customer:549 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", sorry sir I'm just a beginner and I'm trying to learn day by day. Can you edit the answer above so I can understand it, sorry for inconvenience sir. and Thank you for the help

Comment: No problem! we're all learning day by day! As the error said, you have an syntax error, check if you are closing all the brackets..

Comment: I will edit my answer above commenting and explaining the code asap

Comment: hi sir thank you so much, ill wait for the answer thank you so much :)

Comment: i tried this $.each(response.customer.forEach(function(key, item) { }); but it gives me syntax error and argument error